# Countable subsets of reals injecting into reals implies $\omega_1$ distinct reals

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am working through this problem: work in ZF, assume there is an injection $f:\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, show that there are $\omega_1$ distinct reals. Here, $\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all countable subsets of reals.

I think I have the right approach but I am stuck on finishing off the argument. Here's my attempt: without loss of generality we identify $\Bbb R$ with $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$; there is a surjection $\pi: \mathcal{P}(\omega)\rightarrow \omega_1$ by mapping codes of well-orderings to their ordertypes, and non-codes to $0$. Then, by taking pointwise preimage of $\pi$, there is an injection $g:\omega_1\to \mathcal{P(P}(\omega))$. I think the next thing to do is to somehow restrict the range of $g$ to $\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(\mathcal{P}(\omega))$ and then compose it with the injection we assume exists. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Where did you find that problem?

Comment: @AsafKaragila this is from UCLA's logic quals, [fall 2003](https://secure.math.ucla.edu/gradquals/data/logic-03F.pdf), question 1

Comment: Thanks. That's a really nice question. But your approach can't "just work", since it is consistent with ZF that there is no injection from $\omega_1$ into $\mathcal P_{\omega_1}(\Bbb R)$. The linear order on $\mathcal P_{\omega_1}(\Bbb R)$ needs to come into play, one way or another.

Comment: I see, thanks! Back to the drawing board then...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does choice for countably infinite sets of reals imply the existence of $\omega_1$-many reals? (We run into this if we change the domain of $f$ to $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Do you mean choice from countable sets or reals, or countable choice for sets of reals? I'll sleep about it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean a single function $c:[\mathbb{R}]^\omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $c(x)\in x$ for all $x\in[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ - a choice function for the specific set $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$.

Comment: @Noah: Well, given any countable set, we can use $c$ to well-order it, simply apply $c$ until the set is exhausted (or a finite remainder is left). Now, on its own it's not quite enough to conclude that there is an injection into $\Bbb R$, since we might get arbitrarily high order type in the resulting recursion (e.g. if a set is well-ordered in $\Bbb R$, choose the minimum). Nevertheless, I think that'd be enough to get a uniform bijection between all the densely-ordered subsets. And that might be enough.

Comment: @Noah: Right, from such a $c$ we can uniformly enumerate all countable sets, which is an injection from $[\Bbb R]^\omega\to\Bbb R^\omega$, and by your answer below we're done. The way to do is to note that it is enough to find a canonical injection from every set into $\Bbb Q$, moreover it is enough to do so for densely ordered sets: if $A$ is a countable set, then $A\cup\Bbb Q$ is densely ordered and we can enumerate $A$ from an enumeration of $A\cup\Bbb Q$. But now simply use $c$ to choose the elements for the back-and-forth argument and we're done. I think that works, what do you think?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm confused about the back-and-forth part of your argument. To do this, don't we need already an order isomorphic to $\omega$, to be sure that every element will be chosen at some point in the process?

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau: Ah, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to build a well-ordered sequence of reals (which is how "$\omega_1$-many reals" should be thought of in the $\mathsf{ZF}$ setting), the most natural tool to look at is **transfinite recursion**. Without the axiom of choice, this is really the only good way we have of building long well-ordered sequences.

So suppose $f:\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is injective. Do you see a way to "iteratively" use $f$ to build a long sequence of reals?

HINT: start with $f(\emptyset)$ ...

> We define a sequence of reals $(a_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_1}$ recursively as follows: $$a_\eta=f(\{a_\beta:\beta<\eta\}).$$

This $\omega_1$-sequence of reals is clearly well-defined, so all we have to do is show that it's injective: no real appears twice in the sequence. This is where we use the injectivity of $f$; think about how a real arises as an element of this sequence.

---

Note that here I've used the broad notion of countable, where finite sets are considered countable. What if we don't? That is what if $f$ only acts on *countably infinite* sets of reals?

Well, then we hit a bit of a problem: we have to worry about "stalling." Since our recursion can't start at $\emptyset$ anymore, we have to start by picking some countably infinite $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ to feed into $f$. The problem now is if $f$ spits out an element of $X$ - either now, or later on down the road - we'll stop generating new elements of our sequence. Put another way, we need to find an $X$ such that the recursively-defined sequence $$r_\alpha=f(\{r_\beta:\beta<\alpha\}\cup X)$$ never hits $X$.

If no such $X$ exists, then we can extract from $f$ a **choice function** for countably infinite sets of reals: just take $r_\alpha$ for the least $\alpha$ which yields an element of $X$. So the "strong" version of the question reduces to:

> Does "There is a choice function for the set of countably infinite sets of reals" imply "There is an $\omega_1$-sequence of distinct reals?"

This actually seems nontrivial to me - by which I mean I don't know how to solve it. :P Presumably Asaf knows ...

Comment: oh wow I completely missed this in all my attempts to prove this with some kind of coding... thank you!

Comment: @ikrto Happens all the time!

Comment: For the "strong" version where countable means countably infinite, an easy way to do it is to compose $f$ with an injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose image doesn't intersect $\mathbb{N}$. We can then begin the induction at $\mathbb{N}$. But it doesn't answer the "choice function" case.